# Process Builder - Account Field Update after Lead Conversion

Tags: process-builder

I have a process that maps a **custom field from the Lead** Object to a **standard field on the Account** Object and it also populates **a lookup on the Opportunity**, upon conversion.

It works perfectly fine, but I want it now to only map the value, if the Account is a new Account rather than existing.

- The process fires when a record is created or edited.
- Nod Criteria - conditions are met:

  **[Lead].IsConverted = TRUE**
- Update Records: **[Lead].Converted Account ID** - meet all conditions:

  Condition: 1. **Created Date = DATETIMEVALUE([Lead].ConvertedDate])**

  Update Records:  **standard field = [Lead].custom_field__c**

  - Update Records: **[Lead].Converted Opportunity ID**

**Contact = [Lead].ConvertedContactId**

The PB doesn't populate the standard field on Account, because of the condition.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.